# PHP - How to handle real test doubles that should live in the app namespace?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a client class which uses the magic `__call` method to construct and endpoint class.

```
class Client
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $className = "\\App\\Endpoints\\" . ucfirst($name);

        if (! class_exists($className)) {
            throw new InvalidEndpointException("The `{$name}` endpoint was not configured.");
        }

        return new $className($this->getHttpClient());
    }

    // other methods
}
```

My namespace for endpoints is `App\Endpoints`. Worth mentioning that all my endpoints extend from an abstract Endpoint class which contains all the logic needed. The endpoints themselves are pretty much empty with them only containing the endpoint url or in some cases some additional methods non REST methods.

Now I want to test the magic method and don't really want to use a real endpoint from that namespace but rather want to write my own test double. In order to do that I have to put the test double inside the `ClientTest` class under the real namespace `App\Endpoints`. This class will only be available for this test.

This is what I have in my `ClientTest` class

```
namespace App\Tests;

class ClientTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testItReturnsTheCorrectEndpointWhenCalled()
    {
        $resources = $this->client->myTestResources();

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Endpoint::class, $resources);
    }
}

namespace App\Endpoints;

class MyTestResources extends Endpoint
{
    public static $endpoint = 'myTestResources';
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A mock is probably the best way to do this. [There’s some notes about them in the PHPUnit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html), or you could refer to your framework (if you’re using one). Laravel, for example, [has a range of mocks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking).

Comment: I've updated my question with some examples. The problem with mocks is that they will still have to be in the namespace that the magic `__call` is expecting them to be. How would I achieve that with mocks?